# SAPUI5 VIZ column chart integration. Invalid databinding error

Tags: javascript, data-binding, charts, sapui5, graphviz

I am trying to show VIZ chart from SAPUI5 but unable to bind data received from model. It throws **[50017] - Invalid data binding** error. I am posting my code below please have a look at it and help me find the causs.

```
var assignedContentData = {
    "AssignedContentData": [{
        "description": "Capital",
        "newsletter": 2,
        "press_release": 12,
        "letter": 1,
        "notice": 0,
        "bulletin_memorandum": 0
    }, {
        "description": "NA",
        "newsletter": 0,
        "press_release": 0,
        "letter": 0,
        "notice": 1,
        "bulletin_memorandum": 0
    }, {
        "description": "Equity",
        "newsletter": 0,
        "press_release": 4,
        "letter": 0,
        "notice": 5,
        "bulletin_memorandum": 12
    }]
};

var oAssignContentModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    data: assignedContentData
});

sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oAssignContentModel, "oAssignContentModel");
var assignedContentBarChart = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame("assignedContentBarChart", {
    vizType: "stacked_column"
});

var oDatasetAssignedContentBar = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
        name: "Description",
        value: "{description}"
    }],
    measures: [{
        name: "Newsletter",
        value: "{newsletter}"
    }],
    data: {
        path: "/data/AssignedContentData"
    }
});

var feedValueAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    'uid': "valueAxis",
    'type': "Measure",
    'values': ["Newsletter"]
});
var feedCategoryAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    'uid': "categoryAxis",
    'type': "Dimension",
    'values': ["Description"]
});
var feedColorAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    'uid': "color",
    'type': "Dimension",
    'values': ["Newsletter", "Press_Release", "Letter", "Notice", "Bulletin_memorandum"]
});
assignedContentBarChart.setVizProperties({
    plotArea: {
        dataLabel: {
            visible: true,
            formatString: "#,##0"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        title: {
            visible: false
        }
    },

    title: {
        visible: true,
        text: 'Bar Chart'
    }
});

assignedContentBarChart.setDataset(oDatasetAssignedContentBar);
assignedContentBarChart.addFeed(feedValueAxis1);
assignedContentBarChart.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding is incorrect. As your model name is `oAssignContentModel`, it must be reflected in the binding as well in the `data` property assignment:

```
var oDatasetAssignedContentBar = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
        name: "Description",
        value: "{description}"
    }],
    measures: [{
        name: "Newsletter",
        value: "{newsletter}"
    }],
    data: {
        path: "oAssignContentModel>/data/AssignedContentData"
    }
});
```

Or you can remove the name from the model, and you can leave the data binding as it is now:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oAssignContentModel);
```